# Not getting any response from React application run with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, create-react-app

```
Compiled successfully!
web_1  |
web_1  | You can now view react-docker-app in the browser.
web_1  |
web_1  |   Local:            http://localhost:3000
web_1  |   On Your Network:  http://172.18.0.2:3000
web_1  |
web_1  | Note that the development build is not optimized.
web_1  | To create a production build, use yarn build.
web_1  |
```

Running docker-compose up gave the output above, but when I try to connect to the server on my browser, I don't get anything:

```
The server at 172.18.0.2 is taking too long to respond.

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.
```

I entered the port and address:

```
http://172.18.0.2:3000/

http://localhost:3000/
```

I am not getting any error message. I am using a boilerplate project I created with npx create-react-app docker-app.

Is there something wrong.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM node:11.10.1-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: What is your host environment (native Linux, Docker Desktop, Docker Toolbox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Docker Toolbox on Windows 8, because I couldn't use the latest Docker on Windows 10, so the ip was http://192.168.99.100:3000/ It seems that Docker Toolbox works a bit differently, because it has its own ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Can I see your Dockerfile.dev?

It should look something like this:

```
FROM node:13
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: FROM node:11.10.1-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

Comment: Put a line that says `EXPOSE 3000` since you're using port 3000

Comment: Doesn't work, do I need to do anything beside docker-compose up?

Comment: You may have to use `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Are you sure I shouldn't be using a different IP address to connect to it?

Comment: You can see the IP address that container is using by using `docker ps` to view the containers, get the id, then use `docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"` to view the IP.